# How do I fix the $HASP165 JCL error in my COBOL code

Tags: error-handling, cobol, jcl

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quRT8.jpg)

I just started to learn COBOL, and I keep getting a JCL error. In the previous lab I was given the exact same code (with the difference of HELLO1 instead of HELLO2), and I had no errors when submitting. Any help would be appreciated!

Context: It was given as part of a lab. The only hint they give is "It might be a spelling error," but I've triple checked all spelling.

Here is the HELLO2 code.
[part i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anwvk.jpg)
[part ii](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b2lD.jpg)

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=hundreds-hasp165 So probably a JCL error or security violation. Have a close look at the output from the job there will be more information (particularly if it is a JCL error). Also put the JCL in the question and provide more info on the errors.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the error message with us? How shall we be able to help when not details are privieded. Post the JCL, and the job log with all details.

Comment: A JCL error is an error with the JCL, not the Cobol code.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma after `PARM=(OFFSET,NOLIST,ADV)` on line 6.  There may be other problems, we can't see the steps in cataloged proc IGYWCL.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've edited my post to include the HELLO2 code. You do mean there might be something wrong with the code that's linked to the lab, right?

Comment: @Sammb No, I mean you are missing a comma in your JCL where I indicated one was missing.  It's a syntax error, _probably_ resulting in your HASP165 message.  This is a JCL problem having nothing to do with COBOL.